# How to add matches from a search to a list without doing a substitute?

Tags: list, search, vim, match

Example:

```
let hits = [] 

:5s/regex-search/\=join(add(hits, submatch(0)))/g
```

This add all the matches in line 5 to a list.

However it does also a substitute in the text.
I tried to add the '`n`' flag after the '`g`'
but that doesn't add the matches to the list.

Is there any way to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there. First I don't think you need the join. Second, add returns the list with the match added. So you can just select the last element of the list to be the replaced element. (This makes it seem like nothing got replaced)

```
s/regex-search/\=add(hits,submatch(0))[-1]/g
```

Comment: wow.. great. Thank you. It does exactly what I need. BTW why is the last element not be replaced?

Comment: @Remonn I'm sorry I'm not sure what your asking.

Comment: sorry.  Why does the last element of the list makes it seem like nothing got replaced?

Comment: @Remonn add appends `submatch(0)` to the end of the list. When you take the end of the list you get `submatch(0)` back. Which was the thing that was matched in the first place. So you replace the matched item with itself.

Answer (score 1):

With a recent enough Vim version, you can prevent that the actual substitution does take place (and messes up your undo-branches), while the expression on the right side of an :s command is still being evaluated.

You need at least Vim patch [Vim patch 7.3.627](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/Rbx48dxW8Fs/R14P09nNB8UJ) and then you can simply use

```
:s/foobar/\=add(hits, submatch(0))/gn
```